# Shared library distributed in python wheel not found

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, setuptools, python-extensions

I have a python module which contains a C++ extension as well a shared library on which the C++ extension depends.  The shared library is picked up by setuptools as an extra_object on the extension.  After running `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, the module wheel object gets properly generated has a directory structure as follows:

```
+-pymodule.whl
| +-pymodule
| +-pymodule-version.dist-info
| +-extension.so
| +-shared_lib.so
```

To install this wheel, in my python environment I call `pip install pymodule.whl` which copies the python sources as well as the .so files into the environment's `site-packages` directory.

After installing the module, one can then attempt to import the module by calling `import pymodule` in a terminal for the environment.  This triggers an exception to be thrown:

```
ImportError: shared_lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This exception can be resolved by appending the appropriate `site-packages` directory to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable; however, it seems that this should work out of the box, especially considering that python is clearly able to locate `extension.so`.

Is there a way to force python to locate this shared library without having to explicitly point `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at the installation location(i.e. `site-packages`)?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795793/shared-library-dependencies-with-distutils) question works around a similar problem by using package data and explicitly specifying an install location for the shared library.  The issue I have with this approach is that the shared object is decoupled from the extension.  In my case, the shared library and extension are both targets built by the same cmake build.  I had previously attempted to use `skbuild` to build cmake based extentions; however, as per [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-build/scikit-build/issues/272), there is a similar issue in skbuild with including other libraries generated as part of the extension build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared library dependencies with distutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795793/shared-library-dependencies-with-distutils)

Comment: @hoefling, I saw the solution presented in the link you shared; however, that solution is really focused on a 3rd party shared library which is not generated as part of the extension build.  It may work to solve the same issue; however, the object is then decoupled from the extension definition itself and I'm unsure if I can be guaranteed that it will collect this package data only after the extension has completed building.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, this is especially frustrating since creating an egg with python setup.py install _does_ work out of the box.